# Kendo grid nesting - template vs grid in grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using a Kendo grid to make an editable list which should be nested, for example:

---

### John Johnsson      (add score)

Score 1: 15 (remove) 
Score 2: 22 (remove) 
Score 3: 44 (remove)

---

### Paul Paulsson (add score)

---

Score 1: 22 (remove) 
Score 2: 15 (remove)

---

Im wondering how I could make use of kendo grid to make this as efficient as possible? Ive been trying by adding a template that creates each score when you click add score, but it seems that im getting further and further away from actually using kendo and more towards writing my own jquery scripts. Should I instead nest a second kendo grid inside the first?

Comment: please post your code what you done so far. So we can help you.

Comment: Why do you want to use a grid for it? Why not directly a ListView? Check this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/editing **NOTE** ListView can be edited too.